# Select header-tag (e.g. <h2>) with specific text in CSS

Tags: css, xpath, css-selectors

I have a question that I can't figure out after researching for a while:

I have `<h2>`-tags in my wordpress-blogs, and if they have a specific text (like `<h2>Solution</h2>`) I would like to add a specific icon in front of them.

But how do I select this, only using CSS?
I read a lot of posts that say it is not possible - but then I found out about xpath, but I didn't see an example how this would be possible.

I would need a "hint" in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To locate the elements with XPath, you can go with :

```
//h2[text()="Solution"]
```

Meaning : look everywhere on the page for a `h2` element containing the text "Solution".

Comment: Thank you! 
But I misunderstood something: I need to use it in a CSS-file, so the xPath doesn't help, I need a css-selector. As far as I understand, the "text()=..." isn't supported, right? So there is no way to do that in CSS, I need JS?!